# Kafka Stream Metrics Value Reset

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I know I can access metrics via KafkaStreams::metrics().  However is there anyway to reset the metrics after the application has been started?

This would be useful for perf testing.  The process rate metrics are always low because its throughput/sec app is up.

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested in doing perf testing I'd suggest not relying on metrics, but do your own measurements to get more accurate numbers over time.

Currently there's no way to reset metric values inside KafkaStreams